# how to run Node-Red in docker using windows

Tags: windows, image, docker, containers, node-red

I use this command in windows
I actually don't know where *node_red_data* is.

```
docker run -it -p 1882:1880 -v node_red_data:/data nodered/node-red
```

and I got following error.

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /usr/src/node-red/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/.npm/_logs/2021-01-26T11_44_30_912Z-debug.log
```

this is also my log file
this file is created automatically inside my *node_red_data* folder

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   '--no-update-notifier',
1 verbose cli   '--no-fund',
1 verbose cli   'start',
1 verbose cli   '--cache',
1 verbose cli   '/data/.npm',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--userDir',
1 verbose cli   '/data' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v10.23.1
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /usr/src/node-red/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: Failed to parse json
5 verbose stack Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''
5 verbose stack     at parseError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:470:11)
5 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:105:26)
5 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:52:5
5 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
5 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
6 verbose cwd /usr/src/node-red
7 verbose Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard
8 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "--no-update-notifier" "--no-fund" "start" "--cache" "/data/.npm" "--" "--userDir" "/data"
9 verbose node v10.23.1
10 verbose npm  v6.14.10
11 error code EJSONPARSE
12 error file /usr/src/node-red/package.json
13 error JSON.parse Failed to parse json
13 error JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''
14 error JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
14 error JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

any help?

Comment: That log implies that the `/usr/src/node-red/package.josn` is empty which would mean that the docker image is broken. I would suggest deleting the local instance of `nodered/node-red` image and then run the docker command, and it should download it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey the issue you are facing originates in mounting the volume (-v ...) you need to pass a valid Windows Path as an argument. For more information: [Official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Command to run Node-RED as a Docker container: `docker run -p 1880:1880 -it -v "<Path-on-your-Windows-OS>:/data" nodered/node-red`

Where `<Path-on-your-Windows-OS>` e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\node-red-docker`

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I don't know where is node-red-docker file is . I actually don't know what file I must mount to my docker container

Comment: it even doesn't work with following command `docker run -it -p 1889:1880 -v ${PWD}:/data nodered/node-red`

Comment: You need to mount a folder to Node-RED, not a file. Make sure, the folder you are mounting already exists and is empty.

Comment: I mounted an empty folder and after running the command it gives me this log file ,I put the log on my question.

Comment: Is there the `package.json` file in your directory? Maybe try starting Node-RED without a volume to see if that works on your machine: `docker run -p 1880:1880 -it nodered/node-red`

Comment: @cellularegg the `package.json` in the failure is in `/usr/src/node-red` which is part of the initial build. This makes me think the container is corrupt (which is strange) and needs re-pulling.

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading the docker image? (`docker rmi nodered/node-red` and `docker pull nodered/node-red`)

Answer (score 0):

I just made my own node-red instance. I couldn't work with node-red image.

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/node-red
RUN npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
CMD node-red
```

Comment: This is not going to safely persit any of your flows, they will be lost if you ever restart the container.

Comment: I used docker compose to mount my flows. and everything looks ok

Comment: @hardillb that's not a problem when you use volume mounted to /data

Comment: @Kickaha Yes, but with a totally custom Dockerfile as the OP has used here, Node-RED is not setup to use `/data` at all.